# dbGetQuery R, error al hacer una consulta con mas de 1000 valores

Tags: r, sql, datatable, rjava

Estoy realizando una consulta de una tabla con el paquete `RJDBC`, creo la conexión y todo funciona bien, el problema viene cuando intento filtrar por una de las variables.

De todos los datos que tengo solo necesito aquellos que hacen que la `variable1` sea igual a `id1`, `id2`, así hasta `id2000`.

Una vez hecha la conexión, creo un vector con todos los posibles valores y filtro en la consulta.

Se que una solución posible es obtener todos los datos y luego filtrar, pero creo que ganaría tiempo en la consulta si pudiera realizar este filtro dentro de la consulta.

Con pocos valores no da error pero cuando paso de 1000 me da el sitguiente error Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for select ...

Parte del codigo:

```
valores <- c(id1, id2,..., id2000)

datos <- data.table(dbGetQuery(conexion,paste0("select *
                                                from tabla 
                                                where variable1 in(",valores,")
                                                ")))
```

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que **en `Oracle` existe un límite de 1000 elementos en la clausula `IN`**, es decir no puedes indicar más de esta cantidad de valores. Podrías dividir todo en múltiples consultas, por ejemplo:

```
valores <- seq(10000)
lapply(
    split(valores, ceiling(seq_along(valores)/1000)),
    FUN=function(x) {
        sql <- paste0("select * from tabla where variable1 in (", paste0(x, collapse=','),")")
        data.table(dbGetQuery(conexion, sql))
    }
) -> resultados

datos <- rbindlist(resultados)
```

Con `split(valores, ceiling(seq_along(valores)/1000))` generamos una lista dividiendo el vector original `valores` en conjuntos de 1000 elementos, luego simplemente le aplicamos una función que construye la sentencia `sql` y invoca la misma con `dbGetQuery()`, al final tendremos una lista de `data.tables` que podemos unir en uno solo, con `datos <- rbindlist(resultados)`

Por otro lado, como te comenté inicialmente, revisa el código para construir la sentencia mediante el `paste()` ya que no funciona como esperas que lo haga.

Comment: Hola,
El problema viene cuando los valores son más de 1000, es decir, si el in es (1,2,3,...1001), en ese momento dbGetQuery da error.

Quizas una posible solución seria hacer dos vectores con menos de 1000 elementos y hacer dos consultas, no se si aplicando Lapply se podría hacer.

Un saludo,

Comment: @Uko, ¿has probado el código de mi respuesta? ¿te sigue dando error? ¿El mismo u otro?

Comment: El codigo de tu respuesta me vale, pero si dentro del in hay menos de 1000 elementos, cuando dentro del in hay mas de 1000 elementos es cuando da el error.

Comment: Te entiendo. Que base de datos estás usando?

Comment: Es una base de Oracle.

Comment: @Uko, ahora sí Oracle tiene un límite de 1000 valores en una clausula IN, en un rato edito mi respuesta

Comment: Hola,
Lo he probado y funciona bien.
Muchas gracias!!!